# Node JS server hangs up on high load. DB pool connections are used up completely stop responding

Tags: node.js, postgresql-9.3, pg

We are using node.js(V 3.7.2) with pg pool module (V 5.1.0) and set the maxconnections to 20. Until the load is manageable only three connections at the most from the pool are being used. We typically see only a handful of database connections from any given server( We have six servers each having 2 worker node processes). When we approach loads of 18K users or more, something causes the Node.JS requests to get backed up. When a server gets too far behind, it seems to enter an unhealthy state and never recovers and the number of connections used from connection pool jumps to 20 and the connections never enter the pool again. Also the connections seem to stay in idle state on the DB side. We have to take that server out of the load balanced pool and restart it before it can be placed back in the pool again. During this time other servers may be working just fine. We do see database loads spike during those times but we are not able to correlate those issues. At least one time we saw active connections in PostgreSQL for a server that had been rebooted. We had to manually kill those in PostgreSQL before the system started working normally again.

Comment: can you please give code access so that.. i can trace the issue. I am postgresql and node developer.

Comment: you can reach me at sunil.prajapati590@gmail.com

Comment: module.exports.methName = function (Id, newId, reason, client, logger, callback) {
var insertQuery = query;
  var query = client.query({
   text: insertQuery
   ,values: [Id, newId, reason]
  },
  function(err, result) {
   logger.debug("checking query");
   if(err){
    logger.error(' insert query :' + err);
    callback(err);
   }else{
    logger.debug('result = ' + result.rowCount);
    var resultJsonObj = {}; 
    resultJsonObj.result = result.rowCount; 
    callback(null, resultJsonObj);
   }
  });
}